# Can arduino nano get data from two different application?

Tags: arduino, serial-port

So, is it possible that Arduino Nano get data and process it from two different desktop applications through com port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM ports can only be held open by a single application at a time, and it must be properly closed before it can be opened by the next.

Depending on what you need to do, you could develop a proxy service which will be the go-between for the other applications -

This proxy service will be the only service  that will connect to the Arduino, and then it will become the orchestrator for the other service that need to interact with the device.